# Is Null equal to $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Say I have a matrix $A$ and its row reduced echelon form looks like this:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &-3 &2 &-7\\
0  &0 &0  &0\\
0  &0 &0  &0\\
0  &0 &0  &0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I see it has $3$ free variables.... does this mean that the $\text{Null}(A) = \mathbb{R}^3$?
.... Or is the $\text{Null}(A) = \mathbb{R}^4$ because there are four columns. I don't think I understand the concept very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The Nullspace of $A$ lies within $\mathbb R^4$, 4 as in the number of columns (and not $\mathbb R^3$). It is given by the solutions to first equation that you found, $x_1-3x_2+2x_3-7x_4=0$.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly say $\operatorname{null}(A) \cong \mathbb{R}^3$, but all this is saying is that the null space is $3$-dimensional. If you want to say what the null space is *equal* to then you need to do more work; in particular, it needs to be expressed as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$.